# Find all possible links in a website / Screen-Web Scraping with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping, web-crawler, web-search

Sort of an open-ended question here. I needed to go across a Job site and search for a Job Description tag and a Skill requirement (I'm done with this). I basically wanted to know, how do I crawl across the site? As in, go from test.com to test.com/a and so on....?? Basically, crawl the page.

This is my code to search within the page. I need to find all the possible such pages in the site and get the link. THIS IS NOT HOMEWORK. I'm just doing this on the side...

```
import urllib2
import re

html_content = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.ziprecruiter.com/job/Systems-     Engineer/b5452eab/?source=customer-cpc-indeed').read()

matchDescription = re.findall('Bachelor', html_content);
matchSkill = re.findall('VMware', html_content);


print matchDescription
print matchSkill

if ( len(matchDescription) and len(matchSkill) )== 0: 
   print 'I did not find anything'
else:
   print 'My string is in the html'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `Scrapy` or some other existing scraping framework. Otherwise, you need to find the necessary links manually using `lxml` or some other HTML parser and crawl them using some manual mechanism based on `urllib` or something like that and some data structures to store input and output data.